Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [/var/task/bootstrap /opt/bootstrap]
I am attempting to deploy an aws lambda function written in golang. However i get the following error:
 Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [/var/task/bootstrap /opt/bootstrap]

    IntradaySchedulerLfn := awslambda.NewFunction(stack, &name, &awslambda.FunctionProps{
        FunctionName: jsii.String(name),
        Runtime:      awslambda.Runtime_PROVIDED_AL2(),
        Code:         awslambda.AssetCode_FromAsset(jsii.String("src"), nil), // Include all assets under src/
        Handler:      jsii.String("stock-scheduler/intraday/1min/bootstrap"),
        Timeout:      awscdk.Duration_Seconds(jsii.Number(300)),
        Vpc:          vpcDetails.VPC,
        SecurityGroups: &[]awsec2.ISecurityGroup{
            vpcDetails.DefaultVPCSG,
        },
        Environment: &map[string]*string{
            "ENVIRONMENT":          jsii.String("prod"),
            "ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY": jsii.String("89VZ0I4T4ZB424ED"),
        },
        MemorySize:    jsii.Number(256),
        LoggingFormat: awslambda.LoggingFormat_JSON,
        Tracing:       awslambda.Tracing_ACTIVE,
    })

    GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o src/stock-scheduler/intraday/1min/bootstrap src/stock-scheduler/intraday/1min/bootstrap.go
    cdk deploy --all

if i alter the code and handle below it then works.
        Code:         awslambda.AssetCode_FromAsset(jsii.String("src/stock-scheduler/intraday/1min"), nil),
        Handler:      jsii.String("main"),

However i need to reference other shared code that is not contained within src/stock-scheduler/intraday/1min. It is contained in src/utils/.json
I have checked the produced lambda by downloading the zip. bootstrap binary file is present in path used stock-scheduler/intraday/1min/bootstrap

Did any of the answers work?

For Go Lambdas, the binary must be named bootstrap and it must be at the root of the zip file if the code is a Zip archive. From the docs:

For Go functions that use the provided.al2 or provided.al2023 runtime in a .zip deployment package, the executable file that contains your function code must be named bootstrap. If you're deploying the function with a .zip file, the bootstrap file must be at the root of the .zip file.

So you can include other files in your zip archive, but you need to ensure that the bootstrap binary is at the root. You can move it there as part of your build script.

Build your binary named bootstrap at the root of the directory/zip file as shown below and then deploy your lambda.
env GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bootstrap main.go

Here is the snippet of the serverless file
functions:
  ServerHealthCheck:
    handler: bootstrap
    events:
      - http:
          path: /ping
          method: GET

And also make sure your runtime is not gox.1 as before. Change your runtime as shown below.
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: provided.al2
  region: us-east-1
  stage: ${opt:stage}


When you are using AWS CDK from Go, did you try awscdklambdagoalpha.NewGoFunction?
awscdklambdagoalpha.GoFunctionProps has an Entry field where you can define the entry point:
go.NewGoFunction(this, jsii.String("handler"), &GoFunctionProps{
    Entry: jsii.String("lambda-app/cmd/api"),
})

See a working example here.

Ive not tried yet, what is the difference. It appears that NewGoFunction is in alpha? Will this also allow me to reference a shared code directory? How does it build the go binary?
